# MATLAB: modify import list of other scopes dynamically?

Tags: matlab

So, is there a way in MATLAB to modify the import list of a scope different from the current one? That is, I would like to be able to do this:

```
function import_mypackage()
    evalin('caller', 'import mypackage.*');
end
```

This doesn't work. No error is produced when calling `import_mypackage`, but the namespace contained in mypackage is not imported, i.e:

```
function foo()
    import_mypackage;
    g(); % Wanted mypackage.g() but got: Undefined function or variable 'g()'
end
```

I know that you can modify dynamically the import list of the current scope either using `eval` or by passing a variable to `import()`. However, I cannot find any way to modify the import list of other scopes. Is there any way?

**EDIT:** Rody Oldenhuis found in his answer a strange behavior of function import. He suggested that `evalin` actually modifies the import list of the caller but that such list is cleared once you return from `import_mypackage`. However, I think that what is happening is that `import` expressions always evaluate in the current worspace. See:

```
function import_mypackage()
   evalin('caller', 'L = import(''mypackage.foo'');');
   foo; % It works! So the import happened in this workspace
end
```

Modified from Rody's response:

```
function foo()
   import mypackage.f;
   import_mypackage;
   L  
   import
end
```

will print:

```
L = 

    'mypackage.foo'


ans = 

    'mypackage.f'
```

indicating the L was set to the import list of `import_mypackage` scope but that it never really cleared the import list of `foo()`.

**EDIT:** @RodyOldenhuis

The reason why I want to mess around with the import list of the caller scope is that I want to define an "aliased" version of `import()`. Such `alias_import()` would allow the user to define package aliases so that:

```
alias_import my_toolbox
```

may be equivalent to:

```
import my_toolbox_v1.*
```

or to:

```
import my_toolbox_v2.*
```

that is, I want to be able to maintain several versions of a toolbox and control dynamically the version that is being imported. This is useful for comparing results between different `my_toolbox` versions or whenever you want to ensure that certain `my_toolbox` version will be used. All without having to go to the code and manually change import directives in hundreds of functions whenever I am upgrading to a new version of `my_toolbox`. Of course there is the alternative of making this in an indirect way, like:

```
import(alias_import('my_toolbox'))
```

so that `alias_import` will not perform the actual importing but simply will produce the input to the built-in `import`. This is perfectly fine but a bit more verbose and that is why I would have liked `alias_import` to modify the caller's import list. But after seeing the weird behavior of `evalin()` I think I rather leave things like they are now.

Comment: So, I'll be the one to ask: why?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis a bit long story but see my last EDIT in the question for the key idea

Comment: If you have a bunch of directories `+my_package_v1`, `+my_package_v2` etc., isn't it much easier to use a symlink? Like `ln -s +my_package_v4 +my_package` in linux, `mklink +my_package +my_package_v4` in windows

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis There are few problems with using symbolic links: (1) Your aliases names can only be valid package names, i.e. no 'my_package_v1.0.2', and no shortcuts, i.e. not possible to use 'my_package' as an alias for 'globalpkg.subpackage.my_package', (2) requires a lot of messing around with the file system if you modify aliases during runtime, (3) dangerous in a multiuser environment, as you don't know what directories other users may have added to their path, (4) only valid for global aliases. Using `alias_import` there is a way to define aliases in a per-package basis.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have stumbled upon some odd behavior (I'm not using the workd "bug" until I'm sure this is not what Mathworks intended :).

It seems that

```
function import_mypackage()
    evalin('caller', 'import mypackage.*');
end

function foo()
    import_mypackage;
    g(); 
end
```

does not work, but

```
function import_mypackage()
    evalin('caller', 'L = import mypackage.*');
end

function foo()
    import_mypackage;
    L  
    import
end
```

shows

```
L = 
    'mypackage.*'

ans = 
    Empty cell array: 0-by-1
```

which implies that the import list in the caller (`foo`) is cleared when the function `import_mypackage` goes out of scope.

I'd say this is at least unwanted behaviour, and I'd say this is a case for a [bug report](http://www.mathworks.nl/support/faq/bugreportsfaq.html).

As a work-around, use something like

```
function L = import_mypackage()
    L = import('mypackage.*');
end

function foo()
    L = import_mypackage;        
    import(L{:});

    % do stuff with pacakge contents
    ...
end
```

which I think is advisable over `evalin` anyway.

Comment: Interesting, at least this means that the `evalin` really got into `import` as there is a return value. However, I don't think we can conclude that the import list was actually modified and then cleared when exiting `import_mypackage`. I'll edit my question to show what I mean.

Comment: @GermanGomez-Herrero: I think it gets cleared. If you call `evalin('caller', 'g()')` directly after the import, it works. But not when you do this in the caller, *after* the function with the `evalin` terminates...

Comment: OK this makes it even more confusing. You might be right but then, why previous imports in the caller are not cleared as well?

Comment: @GermanGomez-Herrero: Not sure what you mean...it all stops working after `import_mypackage` terminates

Comment: @GermanGomez-Herrero: Ah, wait, I see your edit now. Strange stuff happening here...Yet another reason to avoid `evalin` :) Anyway, you said you found a legit reason to do it this way, can you explain what that is?

Comment: It looks like `evalin()` tries to evaluate the expression in the specified workspace but, if it fails, it evaluates it in the current workspace. If you define a function `puu()` in the same file that contains `import_mypackage()` then `evalin('caller', 'puu()')` will work even though the caller knows nothing about `puu()`. However, the same is not true for nested functions... weird stuff